# adobe air for android on flex: how do I delete all the application data?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe

I need to delete all the application data directories on the exit of an application:

```
/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/.AIR
/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/webviewCache
/data/data/air.<appID>/databases
```

But I get each time the "directory not found error"

Can anybody help me my a PRACTICAL code snippet? This is from my application descriptor:

```
<id>test01</id>
<filename>test01</filename>
<name>test01</name>
```

I know this is possible, but probably I'm typing in a wrong way the directories.

I know also this is not a best practice, but for security reasons I need to delete all the stagewebview cache and autofill form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.applicationStorageDirectory` is the thing you are looking for...
It points directly to the application's private storage directory.

[Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

the link is of not much help in this context. But I've found the solution. I was developing in debug mode so the correct application directory is /data/data/air.myappid.debug/ thanks anyway for the help! As of many of us know applicationdirectroy.nativepath gives an empty string on android.